# $avg returns no value in MongoDb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, monk, mongodb-aggregation

I'm working with NodeJs and MongoDb on Raspbian. I'm using monk as a driver.
I have documents in the database that look like this:

```
var data = {
  ga  : id,       // Group address format (string)
  val : val,      // raw value (float)
  ts  : now       // JavaScript time stamp
}
```

I'm using this code to retrieve grouped and aggregated data:

```
const dbRawColl = req.db.get('raw'); // this is the collection
var project = {
    $project:{
      _id: 0,
      d: { $add: [ new Date(0), "$ts" ] },
      v: "$val"
    }
  };
  // filter by (this works)
  var match = { $match: {  'ga': '0/7/71' } };
  // group results
  var group = { 
    $group: { 
      _id:  { day: { $dayOfMonth: '$d' } },
      min: { $min: '$v' },
      max: { $max: '$v' },
      avg: { $avg: '$v' },
      count: { $sum: 1 } 
    } 
  };
dbRawColl.aggregate([ match, project, group ], function(e, docs) {
  // send "docs" here
}
```

The query works, I see a number of grouped results per day. The answer I get looks like this

```
[{ "_id": { "day": 20 }, 
   "min": "16.38",
   "max": "29.64",
   "avg": 0,
   "count": 2687},
 ... more results omitted for clarity
]
```

The question is: why does "min" and "max" returns proper results while "$avg" is always 0. What prevents "$avg" from doing it's job. It's hardly exactly 0 because of roughly 50000 samples in the DB with a huge range of values (from 10 to 30).

Side question: Why does "min" and "max" returns strings as a result? The value itself appears valid to me looking at the samples.

OS, Node, Express, MongoDb are all current version as of 8/2016.

Edit to answer question, this is a typical document:

```
{
  ga  : "0/7/71",     // Group address format (string)
  val : "24.45",      // raw value (float)
  ts  : 12345678909   // JavaScript time stamp
}
```

The value is obviously a string. Some values are actual strings, so converting all to number will not work. But for the fields I ask for with my $match it's guaranteed that the values are convertable to Number.

Comment: `$avg` will only work with values of a numeric type, not a string. For `$min` and `$max` to work "numerically" the values also need to be a numeric type. Bottom line, you need to convert all of your `val` values to be actual numbers instead of strings.